# What does duckmap really do?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, raku, map-function, duck-typing

From [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/duckmap)

> `duckmap` will apply `&block` on each element and return a new list with defined return values of the block. For undefined return values, `duckmap` will try to descend into the element if that element implements `Iterable`.

But then:

```
my $list = [[1,2,3],[[4,5],6,7]];

say $list.deepmap( *² ); # [[1 4 9] [[16 25] 36 49]]
say $list.duckmap( *² ); # [9 9]
```

[deepmap](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/deepmap) behaves pretty much as expected, but I can't really make any sense of what `duckmap` is doing.

This question is related to [this issue in perl6/doc](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/943). It can be solved with "They couldn't be more different", but I would like to find some examples where they do the same, and when they don't, try and understand really what's going on.

Comment: The `[9,9]` is squaring the element count in the sublists.  Try adding or removing an element to check.  Besides the other helpful answers, documentation efforts may find S32-list/duckmap.t of interest: https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S32-list/duckmap.t

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *duck* in `duckmap` refers to *duck-typing*; that is “if it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it must be a duck.”

```perl6
> say [1,2.2,"3.4",4,"a"].duckmap(-> Str $_ { use fatal; .Int }).perl
[1, 2.2, 3, 4, "a"]
```

(`use fatal` is there so that the `"a".Int` failure object becomes a thrown exception, so that `duckmap` catches it and returns the original data instead)

This is useful for changing small portions of the input without having to specially deal with every possible input.

```perl6
> say [1,2.2,"3.4",4,"a"].map(-> $_ { $_ ~~ Str ?? .Int // .self !! .self }).perl
[1, 2.2, 3, 4, "a"]
> say [1,2.2,"3.4",4,"a"].deepmap(-> $_ { $_ ~~ Str ?? .Int // .self !! .self }).perl
[1, 2.2, 3, 4, "a"]
```

There are more differences between `duckmap` and the other `map`s, but they all are there for this basic premise.

---

```perl6
> [ [<a b c>], [1,2,3], [[4,5,6],] ].duckmap(-> @_ where .all ~~ Int { @_.Str } ).perl
[["a", "b", "c"], "1 2 3", ["4 5 6"]]

> [ [<a b c>], [1,2,3], [[4,5,6],] ].map(-> @_ { @_.all ~~ Int ?? @_.Str !! @_.self } ).Array.perl
[["a", "b", "c"], "1 2 3", [[4, 5, 6],]] # doesn't match, as map is one level deep
```

(Note that you can't do the above at all with `deepmap`, as it goes too deep)
In order to get the same behaviour out of `map`, would require potentially much more work.

Answer (score 3):

`duckmap` goes deep only if `&block` can not be called on Array.
`$_` can be Array in `-> $_ { $_² }`.

Try

```
say $list.duckmap( -> Int $_ {$_²} ); #returns [[1 4 9] [[16 25] 36 49]]
```

There, `duckmap` goes deep.